# swift2で「Type 'クラス名' does not conform to protocol 'SKPaymentTransactionObserver'」のエラーが発生

Tags: swift2

swift1.2で実装していたアプリを、今回アップデートする事になり、swift2.2で書きなおしています。
その中で、storekitのSKPaymentTransactionObserverを使っているクラスで
「Type 'クラス名' does not conform to protocol 'SKPaymentTransactionObserver'」
のエラーが発生してしまっております。

SKPaymentTransactionObserverのプロトコル

```
paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])
```

は、実装済みで、optionalのプロトロルは

```
paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError error: NSError!)
paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue!)
```

が、実装済みでした。
swift1.2の時は、問題なく動いていたのですが、swift2.2でコンパイルが出来なくなってしまい、困っております。

他のoptionalなプロトコルも書いてみたりしたのですが、エラーが解消されませんでした。

何か、エラーの原因がおわかりになる方、いらっしゃいましたらご教授頂けますと幸いでございます。

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: Xcode 7.3.1で試してみましたが、唯一の必須メソッドである`paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])`を正しく実装していれば、表題のエラーが出ることはありません。できればそのクラス全体を編集することなく(メソッドの内側は必要ありませんが、外側は重要です)全てお示しいただくことはできませんか。

Comment: そういえば、optionalなメソッドである`paymentQueue(queue:restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:)`や、`paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_:)`では、Swift 2.2では不要であるはずの`!`が付いていますが、必須メソッドの方も、`func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, removedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!)`のようにSwift 1.2の時の書き方のまま「実装済み」のつもりになっていませんか?

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。ご指摘頂きましたとおり`func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, removedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!)`のように、Swift1.2の時の書き方のまま、「実装済み」のつもりになっておりました・・・。こちら、`paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])`とすることで、事象が解消致しました。ご指摘ありがとうございました。

Comment: できればお時間を取って、その内容を「回答」の方に御記載頂けるでしょうか。QAサイトとしては、「回答」のない宙ぶらりんの質問が残るのはあまり好ましくないのです。その後の「承認」も出来るだけお願いします。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。回答の方記載致しました。「承認」も後ほどするように致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le Pere d'OOさま。
コメントありがとうございます。
ご指摘頂きましたとおり

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, removedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!)
```

のように、Swift1.2の時の書き方のまま、「実装済み」のつもりになっておりました・・・。

こちら、

```
paymentQueue(qu‌​eue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])
```

とすることで、事象が解消致しました。
ご指摘ありがとうございました。